# How to get the same component again and again on click of button

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

On click of Add more transactions button
I want the **remove button**, **select transaction search bar** and the **table** to get displayed as the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating an array in your js and every time that button is clicked add a new object in your array. And in your html use for loop to render each row.

```
 dataList = [];
    handleTransactionClick(){
       this.dataList.push({'Remove':'','Transaction Selected':''})
    }
```